# Editing HTML content in native iOS app

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Is there a good way to allow editing of HTML content in a native iOS application?

For example, if you are building an email app and want to allow replying to an email and editing the original message. It needs to pretty much support any valid HTML, including images, styles, etc.

I've tried a contenteditable `UIWebView` as well as using `NSAttributedString` with a `UITextView`, but neither are good solutions - `UIWebView` does not have any way to manage content or cursor position, and `UITextView` will not render HTML that includes images and other elements.

Comment: Since the only thing I can really understand in this is the first sentence, try looking up `contenteditalbe`, [Link Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

Comment: As I mentioned, I've already tried using contenteditable - there is no way to manage the position of the cursor or manipulate content correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're willing to show a `textarea` with `html` code, I think the only way is to go for a mobile rich text editor with a toolbar and stuff, because `contenteditable` uses shortcuts like <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> right?!

Check out these two guys for mobile browsers:

http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/

http://imperavi.com/redactor/

**UPDATE**

For native apps you may try:

http://www.omnigroup.com/omnioutliner

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor

http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear, this is for a native iOS app rather than a website optimized for mobile use.

Comment: Updated. Now it's just a matter of which one suits your needs.